# CakePHP - using $this->Html->link with $this->Html->image....generating ascii instead of actual HTML

Tags: html, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.3.0. I searched in the manual for quite awhile, but I haven't found the answer. I'm trying to use $this->Html->link, along with $this->Html->image. I'm trying to create the ability to click on an image. Any ideas as to why the ascii rendering of quotes is being generated?

Here is my snippet codeset in my view ctp:

```
echo $this->html->tableCells(
        array(
            array(
                array (
                   $this->Html->link($myActivity['Activity']['name'], array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit'), array('title' => '')), 
                            array('align' => 'left')),
                    array ($myActivity['Activity']['status'], array('align' => 'left')),
                    array ($myActivity['Activity']['any_messages'], array('align' => 'left')),
                    $date2,
                    array ($this->Html->link(
                            $this->Html->image('pencil.jpg', array('alt' => 'Edit', 'border' => '0', 'width' => '25')), 
                            array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'), array('title' => ''))
                    ),
                    $this->Html->image('trashcan.jpg', array('alt' => 'Delete', 'border' => '0', 'width' => '25')),
                    $this->Html->image('copy.png', array('alt' => 'Copy', 'border' => '0', 'width' => '25')),
            )
         )  
      );
```

Below is the actual HTML result of the code above. As you can see, the generated HTML is showing ascii version of quotes (") and '<' and '>':

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        <a href="/activities/index.php/users/add" title="">Running</a>
    </td>
    <td align="left">Live</td>
    <td align="left">no</td>
    <td>02/18/13</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/activities/index.php/users/edit" title="">&lt;img src=&quot;/activities/app/webroot/img/pencil.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;Edit&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;25&quot; /&gt;</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="/activities/app/webroot/img/trashcan.jpg" alt="Delete" border="0" width="25">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Below is what I would expect the HTML to look like:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        <a href="/activities/index.php/users/add" title="">Running</a>
    </td>
    <td align="left">Live</td>
    <td align="left">no</td>
    <td>02/18/13</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/activities/index.php/users/edit" title="">
            <img src="/activities/app/webroot/img/pencil.jpg" alt="Edit" border="0" width="25"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="/activities/app/webroot/img/trashcan.jpg" alt="Delete" border="0" width="25">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: complete duplicate of thousand others (see the sidebar)

Answer (score 22):

You need to add the `escape` option to the options array of your `link()` calls. Set it to `false`, like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('mydog.jpg'), '/lol.html', array('escape' => false)
);
```

Comment: Awesome, I knew this would be an easy fix. I'll give it a try later today when I have time. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Why do you have to add the escape option?

Comment: @defaye If you don't set it to `false` then the contents of the link will be escaped, e.g. `>` will become `&gt;` and etc., which means HTML inside your link won't work.

Comment: @MattCain ah got it. Thanks. I noticed there's perhaps a better way of doing an image link by just having `echo $this->Html->image("yourimage.jpg", array("alt" => "your alt", "url" => "http://yourlink"));` am I missing why OP needs it the other way around?

Comment: @defaye I didn't know that, that is a better way of doing it, unless you need to add attributes to the link like OP does, I don't think that provides a way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Html->image('imagename',array('alt'=>'myimage','class'=>'img-responsive'));
```

This is **normal** image without any link, now to wrap it with link tag use

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('imagename',array('alt'=>'myimage', 'title'=>'myimage','class'=>'img-responsive')), [
                      'controller' => 'controllerName',
                      'action'     => 'actionName',
                      'id'         => $value['id'], //if any parameters are passed
                      ],['escape'    => false]);
```

Similarly you can assign the image tag to a variable and use it

```
$myImageVar = $this->Html->image('imagename',array('alt'=>'myimage','class'=>'img-responsive'));

echo $this->Html->link($myImageVar, [
                          'controller' => 'controllerName',
                          'action'     => 'actionName',
                          'id'         => $value['id'], //if any parameters are passed
                          ],['escape'    => false]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's possible to make an image as anchor tag. 
 You just needs to set escape = false for it like below :-

```
<?php
$thumb_img = $this->Html->image('yourimage.png',array('alt'=>'yoursite.com','class'=>'yourclass'));

echo $this->Html->link( $thumb_img, array('controller'=>'yourcontroller','action'=>'youraction'), array('escape'=>false));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo $this->Html->link('', array(
   'controller' => 'Mycont',
   'action'     => 'deletepic',
   $id
), array(
   'confirm'    => 'Are you sure you want to delete the image?',
   'class'      => 'deleteImg'
));
```

I have linked image to in class deleteImg.