# How to add image to form postlink in cake php?

Tags: cakephp

This is what I have right now.

```
$this->Form->postLink(
    __('Delete Client'), 
    ['action' => 'delete', $client->id], 
    ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $client->id)]
)
```

How do I use the options array to add an image to this link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP - using $this->Html->link with $this->Html->image....generating ascii instead of actual HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007396/cakephp-using-this-html-link-with-this-html-image-generating-ascii-in)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Form->postLink(
    $this->Html->image(
        "action-delete.svg", 
        ["alt" => "Delete Client", 'class' => 'action-link']
    ), 
    ['controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'delete', $client->id],
    ['escape' => false, 'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $client->id)]
)
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. Especially as previously written it's not necessarily obvious to readers what you've changed. Is your actual source code all written on one line? How can you read that :P

Answer (score 0):

Please try i works perfect!

```
   echo $this->Form->postLink($this->Html->image('1.png'), ['action' => 'delete',$client->id],['escape' => false, 'title' => 'Delete', 'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?'),$client->id)]);?>
```

Thank You!